# Is possible in any way in Corona/Lua to take advantage of multiple cores on mobile device?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is possible in any way in Corona/Lua to take advantage of multiple cores on mobile device ?
Can you do calculation in another "thread" ( I have lot of calculations which cannot be easily optimised)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For the time being at least, Corona is single-threaded.

I guess you could try using Corona Enterprise thing to hook up with native iOS & Java, but you would have to "cook things yourself".

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there appeard to be no way of doing this in Corona but the other answers are partially wrong or incomplete:

Corona itself is single threaded. So you have two main choices: coroutines and Lua lanes:

1. Coroutines all run in the same thread (so single core) but they are useful when task can be subdivided into small chunks of work, then multiple tasks can run seemingly in parallel.
2. Lanes uses native threads which the OS will run on multiple cores if possible. However it does not appear that Corona supports Lua Lanes currently.

Answer (score -1):

You can use coroutines, even in Corona:

An example, put this in your main.lua somewhere:

```
co = coroutine.create(function ()
           print("hi")
         end)

print (co)

coroutine.resume(co)
```

Reference:

http://www.lua.org/pil/9.html

http://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html